# I have an HP Pavilion dv6 A1U58AV and the headphone jack does not work

Tags: 12.04, sound

Whenever I plug a set of headphones or an aux cable into the headphones jack the computers speakers turn off, but no audio comes out of the headphones or the aux cable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updating ALSA by going to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS fixed the problem.

Comment: updating how? please explain fully what you did otherwise a future reader of this question will not have any idea how you resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lets keep it Ubuntu related ;) and second that means your plugin in the wrong aux port:) their are many times two audio ports, and only one will work with most headphones, also certain headphone aren't compatable